# Plot and mention extremum with corresponding points of extrema

Tags: plotting

Let

```
sigma1[v_]=-0.0000438577 Sqrt[-5.19886*10^8 + 100. v^2];

sigma2[v_]=-1.*Sqrt[-(1.34039*10^13/(
 1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 1.34039*10^12 I) v)) + ((0. + 
   5.49727*10^16 I) v)/(
1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 1.34039*10^12 I) v) + (5.49714*10^15 v^2)/(
1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 1.34039*10^12 I) v) - ((0. + 
   2.74857*10^14 I) v^3)/(
1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 1.34039*10^12 I) v) - (
0.5 Sqrt[-1.20874*10^34 v^2 + (0. + 2.41748*10^33 I) v^3 + 
  2.41748*10^32 v^4 - (0. + 1.20874*10^31 I) v^5 - 
  3.02185*10^29 v^6])/(1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 1.34039*10^12 I) v)];

sigma3[v_]= Sqrt[(-1.34039*10^13 + (0. + 5.49727*10^16 I) v + 
  5.49714*10^15 v^2 - (0. + 2.74857*10^14 I) v^3 - 
  0.5 Sqrt[v^2 (-1.20874*10^34 + (0. + 2.41748*10^33 I) v + 
      2.41748*10^32 v^2 - (0. + 1.20874*10^31 I) v^3 - 
      3.02185*10^29 v^4)])/(1.34039*10^13 - (0. + 
     1.34039*10^12 I) v)];
```

where the use the following parameters:

```
c1=4631.0; c2=2280.1; d=8066.8; eps=0.0168; kap=1; taut=0.1;tauq=0.1;
```

Consider now the following 5th degree Polynomial h[v]:

```
h[v_] =I*sigma2[v]*(1+sigma2[v]^2-v^2/c1^2)*(4*sigma1[v]*sigma3[v]-(2-v^2/c2^2)*((1+sigma1[v]^2)*c1^2/c2^2-2))*(1-I*kap*taut*v-(I*d*v/(kap*(1+sigma1[v]^2)))*(1-I*kap*tauq*v-kap^2*tauq^2*v^2/2))+(eps*c1^2*d*v/(kap*c2^2))*(1-I*kap*tauq*v-kap^2*tauq^2*v^2/2)*(4*sigma2[v]*sigma3[v]*c2^2/c1^2+(2-v^2/c2^2)*(2*c2^2/c1^2-v^2/c1^2-sigma2[v]*(1+sigma2[v]^2-v^2/c1^2)))
```

and further define F(Re(v), Im(v))=Log|h(v)|.

I need a plot like the following Figure 3 from the above information:
[image]

Note that we use the function h(v) instead of D(v) in Mathematica.
Also, it would be nice if possible to show the extremum values and the corresponding points in the figures. Can anyone please help me? I am at basic level in learning Mathematica. Seeking kind help!

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: What is plotted in figure 3: `Log[Abs[h[v]]` or `Abs[Log[h[v]]]`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have to plot `Log[Abs[h[v]]]` (Thanks @user64494 's comment)

Try `DensityPlot`and `Plot3D`:

```
DensityPlot[Evaluate@Log[Abs[h[vre + I vim]]], {vre, 0, 10},{vim, -10, 0 },ColorFunction -> Hue, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate@Log[Abs[h[vre + I vim]]], {vre, 0, 10}, {vim,-10,0 }, AxesLabel -> {"Re[v]", "Im[v]", "Log[Abs[h[v ]]]"},ColorFunction -> Hue, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}]
```

[image]

Comment: `Abs@Log!=Log@Abs`

Comment: For example, `Log[Abs[h[2 - I]]]` results in `18.8443`, but `Abs[Log[h[2 - I]]]` outputs `18.8781`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are plots:

```
ComplexPlot[Log[Abs[h[v]]], {v, 0 + 0*I, 10 - 10*I}]
```

[image]

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[Abs[h[v]]], {v, 0 + 0*I, 10 - 10*I},PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

It is difficult with the extrema since `ComplexExpand[h[s + I*t]]` takes 140.4 MB.The following works.

```
NMaximize[{ComplexExpand[Log[Abs[h[s + I*t]]]], 
s >= 0 && s <= 10 && t >= -10 && t <= 0}, {s, t}]
```

> `{56.0063, {s -> 1.21431*10^-9, t -> -10.}}`

```
NMinimize[{ComplexExpand[Log[Abs[h[s+I*t]]]],s>=0&&s<=10&&t>=-10&&t<=0},{s,t},Method->"DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{-13.3409 + 0. I, {s -> 0., t -> -1.48265*10^-9}}`